# Make a list of consecutive pairs in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I want to make a list of consecutive pairs from a given list, e.g.
given `[1,2,3]` it returns `X=[[1,2],[2,3]]`
I'm a bit confused with the recursions.
I tried with the code above, it returns me the pairs (one at a time) but the append doesn't work.

```
pair_list([X,Y|_], [X,Y]):- 
  append([[X,Y]],[,],L),
  write(L). 

pair_list([_|Tail], XY):- 
  pair_list(Tail,XY).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's consider the following points:

- A clean representation of pairs *is* important.

  - Do *not* use "comma lists" `[A,B]` or "comma pairs" `(A,B)`.
  - Instead, use compound terms having the form `A-B`.
- Stick to the *logically pure* subset of Prolog for maximum code versatility.

A straightforward implementation goes like this:

```
list_adjitems([], []).
list_adjitems([E|Es], Xs) :-
   list_adjitems_previous(Es, Xs, E).

list_adjitems_previous([], [], _).                    % auxiliary predicate
list_adjitems_previous([E1|Es], [E0-E1|Xs], E0) :-
   list_adjitems_previous(Es, Xs, E1).
```

Some sample queries:

```
?- list_adjitems([], Xs).
Xs = [].

?- list_adjitems([a], Xs).
Xs = [].

?- list_adjitems([a,b,c], Xs).
Xs = [a-b,b-c].
```

Does this work in the "reverse" direction, too? (Hint: it does.)

```
?- list_adjitems(Es, []).
   Es = []
;  Es = [A].

?- list_adjitems(Es, [x-y,y-z,z-u,u-v]).
Es = [x,y,z,u,v].
```

Last, let's not forget about the *most general query*:

```
?- list_adjitems(Es, Xs).
   Es = []             , Xs = []
;  Es = [A]            , Xs = []
;  Es = [A,B]          , Xs = [A-B]
;  Es = [A,B,C]        , Xs = [A-B,B-C]
;  Es = [A,B,C,D]      , Xs = [A-B,B-C,C-D]
;  Es = [A,B,C,D,E]    , Xs = [A-B,B-C,C-D,D-E]
;  Es = [A,B,C,D,E,F]  , Xs = [A-B,B-C,C-D,D-E,E-F]
;  Es = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G], Xs = [A-B,B-C,C-D,D-E,E-F,F-G]
…                                                     % ... and so on ...
```

*Works just like it should™.*

Homework: re-run above queries with the code proposed in the other answers!

Answer (score 3):

Learning recursion is essential, so go with damianodamiano' answer. Then consider the basic 'all solutions' tools, like findall/3:

```
?- L=[1,2,3],findall([X,Y],append(_,[X,Y|_],L),Ps).
L = [1, 2, 3],
Ps = [[1, 2], [2, 3]].
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply write:

```
pair([_],[]).
pair([A,B|T],[[A,B]|T1]):-
    pair([B|T],T1).
```

Query:

```
?-pair([1,2,3],L).
L = [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

You don't need to use `append/3`.

Comment: What about `?- pair([], L).` ? IMO that query should succeed.